# C# Convert System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow> to DataTable

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have a datatable which I have filterd using Linq:

```
result = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<string>("id").Contains(values));
```

I have also tried using `CopyToDataTable` methods like

```
result.CopyToDataTable()
```

and

```
result.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>()
```

but they didn't work.
How can I convert `result` to new DataTable?
I have search many Stack Overflow questions and many other tutorials but I can't find what I want.

**UPDATE**

I have concatenated HashSet to comma separated values, I think I should use array of String or HashSet?

Comment: Why do you want it as a new DataTable?  This sounds like you are probably not taking the best approach.  And you probably want to avoid calling `AsEnumerable().Where` because this will download your entire table into memory before doing the filtering. Would be better to filter in the database/sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you create object of `DataTable` and import row in it by calling `ImportRow()` function , that will resolve issue.

[DataTable.ImportRow Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow(v=vs.110).aspx)

Example code.

```
DataTable tblClone = datTab.Clone();
foreach (DataRow datRow in datTab.Rows) 
{

        tblClone.ImportRow(datRow);
}
```

for you it will be like

```
var result = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<string>("id").Contains(values));
DataTable tblClone = myDataTable.Clone();
foreach(DataRow dr in result)
  tblClone.ImportRow(dr);
```

Answer (score 2):

`.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>()` returns a DataTable, it will not modify the variable unless you re-assign it.

```
result = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<string>("id").Contains(values));
```

Then you actually need a DataTable object.

`DataTable resultDT = result.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();`

Edit: As Tim pointed out, if no rows are returned by your query, an exception will be thrown `"The source contains no DataRows"`

You could do something like so;

`DataTable resultDT = result.Any() ? result.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>() : myDataTable.Clone();`

But that will run the query twice (also as Tim pointed out).

Therefore you could convert that to a list object using (`.ToList()`), check the count and do your processing then. That has performance implications in such that you create a new instance of the object (List object).

Doing a `try/catch` with attempt to convert it to `DataTable` also isn't a good idea. See Pranays answer for another great way to achieve the final result.

Comment: You also have to take note that `CopyToDataTable` throws  an exception if no row matched the predicate(so there was no row which ID contained the values, a strange query by the way). You could use `if(result.Any())...`. But that executes the query twice. I prefer `DataTable resultDT=myDataTable.Clone();...foreach(var r in result) resultDT.ImportRow(r);`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks for pointing that out. Will add that in, cheers.